# Why a MQL4 bot does not detect a 5-EMA & 20-EMA cross-over in a StrategyTester run?

Tags: moving-average, mql4, trading, metatrader4, forex

I am a newbie in coding bot for MetaTrader Terminal 4 platform, but I have a decent experience in coding JavaScript for the web.

I just build a simple MQL4 bot, using `EMA(5)` and `EMA(20)` to place an order, but when I try to test it via a StrategyTester run, it keeps showing both condition not met, please what am I doing wrong?

Below is my code *<sub>( https://codeshare.io/5NzvYl )</sub>*

```
input int fastEma_Period = 5;
input int fastEma_ma_Shift = 0;
input int fastEma_ma_Method = 1;              //  EXPONENTIAL
input int fastEma_applied_Price = 0;          //  CLOSED PRICE
input int fastEma_shift_CandleIndex = 0;      //  CURRENT FORMING CANDLESTICK

input int slowEma_Period = 20;
input int slowEma_ma_Shift = 0;
input int slowEma_ma_Method = 1;              //  EXPONENTIAL
input int slowEma_applied_Price = 0;          //  CLOSED PRICE
input int slowEma_shift_CandleIndex = 0;      //  CURRENT FORMING CANDLESTICK

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double fastEmaBar0 = iMA(NULL,0,fastEma_Period,fastEma_ma_Shift,fastEma_ma_Method,fastEma_applied_Price,fastEma_shift_CandleIndex);
double slowEmaBar0 = iMA(NULL,0,slowEma_Period,slowEma_ma_Shift,slowEma_ma_Method,slowEma_applied_Price,slowEma_shift_CandleIndex);
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double fastEmaBar1 = iMA(NULL,0,fastEma_Period,fastEma_ma_Shift,fastEma_ma_Method,fastEma_applied_Price,fastEma_shift_CandleIndex + 1);
double slowEmaBar1 = iMA(NULL,0,slowEma_Period,slowEma_ma_Shift,slowEma_ma_Method,slowEma_applied_Price,slowEma_shift_CandleIndex + 1);

double lotSize = AccountBalance() / 10000;

int maBt;
int maSt;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//---

  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
//---
   enterMarket();
// ExpertRemove();
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
string maCrossOverSignal(double fastEmaBar1, double slowEmaBar1, double fastEmaBar0, double slowEmaBar0)
  {
   string signal;
   if((fastEmaBar1 <= slowEmaBar1) && (fastEmaBar0 > slowEmaBar0))
     {
      signal = "Buy";
     }
   else
      if((fastEmaBar1 >= slowEmaBar1) && (fastEmaBar0 < slowEmaBar0))
        {
         signal = "Sell";
        }
   return signal;
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void enterMarket()
  {
   if(/*OrdersTotal() == 0 &&*/ maCrossOverSignal(fastEmaBar1,slowEmaBar1,fastEmaBar0,slowEmaBar0)== "Buy")
     {
      //continue inside this condition, bcos its not getting met
      Print("time to Buy ");
      maBt = OrderSend(NULL,OP_BUY,lotSize,Ask,100,0,0,"maBt");
      if(maBt > 0)
        {
         if(OrderSelect(maBt,SELECT_BY_TICKET))
           {
            modify(maBt,OrderOpenPrice(),OrderOpenPrice() - 50 * Point,OrderOpenPrice() + 200 * Point,0);
           }
        }
     }
   else
      if(/*OrdersTotal() == 0 && */maCrossOverSignal(fastEmaBar1,slowEmaBar1,fastEmaBar0,slowEmaBar0)== "Sell")
        {
         Print("time to Sell ");
         maSt = OrderSend(NULL,OP_SELL,lotSize,Bid,100,0,0,"maSt");
         if(maSt > 0)
           {
            if(OrderSelect(maSt,SELECT_BY_TICKET))
              {
               modify(maSt,OrderOpenPrice(),OrderOpenPrice() + 50 * Point,OrderOpenPrice() - 200 * Point,0);
              }
           }
        }
      else
        {
         Print("both condition not met");
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"... **what** am I doing wrong?"*

Almost there.

You've missed a tiny, yet cardinal detail. The both assignments of `iMA()`-values are fine, but in a wrong place.

You need to let re-calculate & re-assign `iMA()`-values after each `QUOTE`-message arrival ( per each tick, coming from your FX-Market access mediator ( emulated in StrategyTester runs from past-data, sure ) ).

```
void OnTick() { /*\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ QUOTE-has arrived, i.e.
                                          new prices are known here:
//------------------------------------------- UPDATE each control-DATA now */
fastEmaBar0 = iMA( NULL, 0, fastEma_Period,
                            fastEma_ma_Shift,
                            fastEma_ma_Method,
                            fastEma_applied_Price,
                            fastEma_shift_CandleIndex
                            );
slowEmaBar0 = iMA( NULL, 0, slowEma_Period,
                            slowEma_ma_Shift,
                            slowEma_ma_Method,
                            slowEma_applied_Price,
                            slowEma_shift_CandleIndex
                            );
fastEmaBar1 = iMA( NULL, 0, fastEma_Period,
                            fastEma_ma_Shift,
                            fastEma_ma_Method,
                            fastEma_applied_Price,
                            fastEma_shift_CandleIndex + 1
                            );
slowEmaBar1 = iMA( NULL, 0, slowEma_Period,
                            slowEma_ma_Shift,
                            slowEma_ma_Method,
                            slowEma_applied_Price,
                            slowEma_shift_CandleIndex + 1
                            );
//------------------------------------------- UPDATE
//------------------------------------------- DONE, may start making decisions
   enterMarket();
// ExpertRemove();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much https://stackoverflow.com/users/3666197/user3666197 

The code is working properly now after i declare the moving average output inside the maCrossoOverSignal() function.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped ( if you defer and put the control-variables' update step into some user-defined function, it may work, yet almost sure to be a less responsible design - any other part of the code may or need not call that UDF, resulting in an almost uncertainty, whether these "globals" did get updated already or re-updated ( blocking the time ) or 've never been updated at all. Placing the control-vars update right into the OnTick(){...}-head-part,you spend zero-nanosecond more than needed, yet having 100% "AtomFest Und BombenSichr" certainty the code uses correct & only correct values